# Сортировка ключей словаря по возрастанию

Tags: python, django

Приветствую.

Дан словарь

```
{'2.3': ['0', '1'], '4.9': ['0', '1'], '4.7': ['0', '1'], '3.5': ['0', '1'], '2.4': ['0', '1'], '3.17': ['0', '1'], '4.8': ['0', '1'], '3.6': ['0']}
```

Необходимо отсортировать его по ключам в порядке возрастания. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
for x in sorted(dict_list.keys(), key=lambda x : float(x[:len(x)-1])):
    print(x)
```

Получается

```
2.3, 2.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.17, 4.9, 4.7, 4.8
```

В общем, сортирует он явно как-то не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отсортировать в порядке возрастания ключей? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скажите, а то меня любопытство разобрало, - а что вы пытались вычислить выражением float(x[:len(x)-1])  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вы хотите вернуть отсортированный список ключей/значений, можно просто отсортировать словарь по его ключам:

```
for k in sorted(dict_list.keys()):
    print (k, ':', dict_list[k])
```

Если нужно хранить отсортированные пары ключ/значение, попробуйте использовать `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#отсортирует по возрастанию ключей словаря
OrderedDict(sorted(dict_list.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

[Документация по OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

**UPD**
по просьбе автора сортировка по возрастанию с условием, что 3.17 должно быть последним

```
for i in sorted(dict_list.items(), key=lambda x: (len(x[0]), x[0])):
    print (i[0])
```

Если 3.17 должно быть первым, можно просто добавить `-` в условие:

```
..lambda x: (-len(x[0]), x[0]))
```

Comment: К сожалению в обоих случаях 3.17 выбивается из ряда

{'2.3': ['0', '1'], '4.9': ['0', '1'], '2.4': ['0', '1'], '3.17': ['0', '1'], '4
.8': ['0', '1'], '3.6': ['0'], '4.7': ['0', '1'], '3.5': ['0', '1']}

Comment: `2.3 : ['0', '1'] 2.4 : ['0', '1'] 3.17 : ['0', '1'] 3.5 : ['0', '1'] 3.6 : ['0'] 4.7 : ['0', '1'] 4.8 : ['0', '1'] 4.9 : ['0', '1']` Здесь же правильная последовательность, 3.17 там, где и должно быть.

Comment: Третий. 3.17 < 3.5 Да, что то я затупил. Жаль, необходимо чтобы 3.17 было выше всех остальных 3.*

Comment: какой тогда в этом смысл? это уже не сортировка по возрастанию. Тогда нужно сформулировать, по какому условию нужна сортировка

Comment: Да, вы правы, я сглупил. Буду дальше думать над условием. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @NikPiro пробуйте, теперь 3.17 будет последним. P.S. Спасибо тут говорят поднятием рейтинга и галочкой у ответа :)

Comment: Да, то что надо) рейтинг поднимать еще не могу, извиняйте) ответ отметил как правильный